# Filterizr responsive grid options

Tags: jquery, grid

I'm using a responsive gallery grid called [Filterizr](http://yiotis.net/filterizr/), and I'm confused about where to put certain options.

I have this:

```
      $(function() {
        //Initialize filterizr with default options
        $('.filtr-container').filterizr(
          options = {
             animationDuration: 0.5,
             callbacks: {
                onFilteringStart: function() { },
                onFilteringEnd: function() { },
                onShufflingStart: function() { },
                onShufflingEnd: function() { },
                onSortingStart: function() { },
                onSortingEnd: function() { }
             },

             delay: 0,
             delayMode: 'progressive',
             easing: 'ease-out',
             filter: 'all',
             filterOutCss: {
                opacity: 0.5,
                transform: 'scale(0.5)'
             },
             filterInCss: {
                opacity: 0.5,
                transform: 'scale(1)'
             },
             layout: 'sameSize',
             selector: '.filtr-container',
             setupControls: true
          }
        );
    });
```

But then there is a shuffle method listed on the site, and I don't know where inside options to put it:

```
.filterizr('shuffle')
```

Any hints? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I believe filterizr is not initialized as the options are passed in wrong. You should be doing

```
$(function() {
    //Initialize filterizr with default options
    $('.filtr-container').filterizr({
         animationDuration: 0.5,
         callbacks: {
            onFilteringStart: function() { },
            onFilteringEnd: function() { },
            onShufflingStart: function() { },
            onShufflingEnd: function() { },
            onSortingStart: function() { },
            onSortingEnd: function() { }
         },

         delay: 0,
         delayMode: 'progressive',
         easing: 'ease-out',
         filter: 'all',
         filterOutCss: {
            opacity: 0.5,
            transform: 'scale(0.5)'
         },
         filterInCss: {
            opacity: 0.5,
            transform: 'scale(1)'
         },
         layout: 'sameSize',
         selector: '.filtr-container',
         setupControls: true
      }
    );
});
```

or you should be using the setOptions Method

```
var options = {your options object to override default options};
filterizd.filterizr('setOptions', options)
```